# How do I format numbers as percentages in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the simplest/idiomatic way to format percentages in Scala?

I have the following solution but I'm wondering if a more concise way exists:

```
val value = 0.1456

val s1 = f"the float value is ${value}%.2f" 
val s2= s"the percent value is ${java.text.NumberFormat.getPercentInstance.format(value)}"

value: Double = 0.1456

s1: String = the float value is 0.15
s2: String = the percent value is 15%
```

Comment: or you can just do `Math.floor(value*100).toString + "%"`

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for more of a concise method, the following works and goes along with your initial idea in your code.  It is also easy to add on decimal placement without having to resort to the implicit functionality. Obviously these needs to be used a lot a better solution is with the implicit method.

```
val value = 0.1456
val s2 = val s2 = f"the percent value is ${value*100}%.0f%%"

s2: String = the percent value is 15%
```

just to give a couple of other runs as well (t show rounding down here):

```
val value2 = 0.1416
val s3 = val s2 = f"the percent value is ${value2*100}%.0f%%"

s3: String = the percent value is 14%
```

Example to show adding decimal places:

```
val s4 = f"the percent value is ${value2*100}%.1f%%"
s4: String = the percent value is 14.2%
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "pimp my library" pattern to add the `asPercentage` method to Doubles.

```
implicit class DoubleAsPercentage(d: Double) {
  def asPercentage = java.text.NumberFormat.getPercentInstance.format(d)
}

val s2 = s"the percent value is ${value.asPercentage}"
```

Comment: I think that DoubleAsPercentage can and should be declared as AnyVal (value class) to aviod creating new instance on every asPercentage call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the f string to format the percentage to the relevant decimal places you wish. In this example, it has 4 decimal places however if you only want to return two decimal places, then use .2f in the string below.
To return 3 decimal places, then use .3f etc etc. However if you want more decimal places than suggested; "here they are 4", you will end up with trailing zeros.

```
val percentage = 51.9938

scala> f"I scored $percentage%.8f%% in my exams"

res164: String = I scored 51.99380000% in my exams

scala> f"I scored $percentage%.2f%% in my exams"

res165: String = I scored 51.99% in my exams
```